# How to print output inside curly brace with comma in C, im new in this

Tags: c

I'm trying to make my output like this =
{7,6,5}-{4}-{3,2,1}

or like this

{2,5}-{4}-{3,1}

but I always get this =
765-{4}-321
and
25-{4}-31

this is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main(){

         int size;
         scanf("%d\n", &size);
         int middle = (size - 1) / 2;

         int array[size];
          for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {   
            scanf("%d\n", &array[i]);
        }
        
        for (int i = size - 1; i > middle; i--){
                printf("%d",array[i]);
        }
    
         
        printf("-{%d}-", array[middle]);

        for (int i = middle - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    printf("%d", array[i]);
        }  

}
```

Comment: Your code makes no attempt at printing braces around the first half and second half set of numbers.  Try that first.

Answer (score 2):

Add things to match the output.

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main(){

         int size;
         scanf("%d\n", &size);
         int middle = (size - 1) / 2;

         int array[size];
          for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {   
            scanf("%d\n", &array[i]);
        }
        
        putchar('{');
        for (int i = size - 1; i > middle; i--){
                if (i < size - 1) putchar(',');
                printf("%d",array[i]);
        }
        putchar('}');
    
         
        printf("-{%d}-", array[middle]);

        putchar('{');
        for (int i = middle - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (i < middle - 1) putchar(',');
    printf("%d", array[i]);
        }  
        putchar('}');

}
```

(OP's original indentation is respected)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you only have the curly brackets at `printf("-{%d}-", array[middle]);`. You need to implement it in the for loop because you are only printing it normally in it

Answer (score 0):

You make a mistake a little bit in your code.If you want output like this {2,5}-{4}-{3,1} your code look like as follow.Here the code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int size,i;
    scanf("%d\n", &size);
    int middle = (size - 1) / 2;
    int array[size];
    for ( i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d\n", &array[i]);
    }
    printf("{");
    for (int i = size - 1; i > middle; i--)
    {
        if(i==middle-1)
        {
            printf("%d", array[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d,", array[i]);
        }
    }

    printf("}");
    printf("-{%d}-", array[middle]);
    printf("{");
    for (int i = middle - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {

        if(i==0)
        {
            printf("%d", array[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d,", array[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("}");

}
```